# Default Lifetime for token generated for reset password by a IUserTokenProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

Does anyone know what the default lifetime of a token generated by `IUserTokenProvider` is? I'm using `EmailTokenProvider` to generate a token for resetting a password. But I can't seem to find out how long it will last for.

I understand it can be set on the `DataProtectorTokenProvider`  by setting the property `TokenLifespan`

Does it last forever for a token generated using EmailTokenProvider or is the default 24hrs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some of our users complained of invalid email tokens, I ran a few tests on the EmailTokenProvider and all of them came back at about **8 minutes**, give or take a couple seconds.

This is consistent with my own experience testing Asp.Net password reset forms manually and with the reports from our users.

Comment: Thanks for your investigation in this. I did decide to use the `DataProtectorTokenProvider` to have more control over the token lifespan. But thanks for your response regarding the `EmailTokenProvider`

Answer (score 1):

Ok tucked away on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity
is the following:

> The default TokenLifespan is one day.